# How do I handle Apple Pay when transferring an app between accounts in App Store Connect?

Tags: mobile, app-store, applepay

I need to transfer an app between two developer accounts in App Store Connect. The app uses Apple Pay.

The Apple guidance [1] on this says:

> If you transfer an app that uses Apple Pay, the merchant ID is not transferred along with the app. Transactions continue to be successful as long as the original certificates are valid. However, when you submit an update, a new merchant ID must be created on the recipient’s account.

I read this to mean that I won't see a problem when the app has transferred. However, when I do an update, the merchant identifier will need to be updated.

My questions are:

- When do I need to update the Payment Processing certificate (and how)?
- Since this is tied to the merchant id, will the old one keep working once a new app has been released that has a new merchant id?
- If not, how do I go about swapping the certificate at the PSP end?
- And if I don't need to swap the certificate, what happens when the old account expires?

I have tried to resolve this with Apple, but the the App Store support team just seem to have access to the same public documentation, and were unable to clarify the process.

[1] https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/transfer-an-app/overview-of-app-transfer